# How to display multiple toast from service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, toast

I want to display multiple toast during incoming call state but when i get offhook state it displays the toast but on idle state the toast is not displayed I have use thread and Async task but problem is the same it shows no error so i have nothing in my logcat .
Currently I am using the below method to show toast.

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {  
               public void run() {  
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "import started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                  Log.d("TAG", "Recording Toast stop");
               }  
            });
```

**NOTE:** I have to show toast on Home screen when call ends and the code is running on a service.

Comment: You can use messenger for the same. Pass messenger object to service and when call ends send call back to handler for messenger. In this way you can show toast on home screen

Comment: I am checking the state of phone in service and i want to display toast from service itself